# DepDrop поиск по списку

Tags: php, yii2

Использую DepDrop от katrik. Вот мой код:

```
echo $form->field($country, 'country_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'data'=> $dataCountry,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Выберите страну',
        'id' => 'country_live ',
        'class' => 'select_base',
    ],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['country_id'],
        'url' => Url::to(['/account/child-account']),
        'loadingText' => 'Loading child level 1 ...',
    ]
]);
```

Поля поиска (вверху перед элементами списка) по самому списку нет.

Как его включить?

Comment: И еще один вопрос по ходу - как изменить какой-нибудь параметр виджета, вот если мне нужно допустим placeholder поменять?

Comment: я так понимаю, никто не знает ответа или просто вопрос не интересен, подскажите как закрыть вопрос?